# Android: how to use session management in extranet?

Tags: android

I searched `SharedPreferences` and tried my project but i think something is wrong.

My project is about a company's extranet. Each employee has an android based phone.
The company wants simple android app which use very easily by employees.

The app is used so that an employee can access extranet easily outside the company.

The app has two screens - Login and Register.
Each employee need to have account for example. "someone@company.com" and password then register.

If the user has already registered, there is no need to login again.
I need a mail server name and some attributes such as this.
So all user's domain name and password in the company need to record such as 
`SQLite` or `SharedPreferences` and each one logs to their own account on android phone.
According to project can you tell me which one is right for this app?

Comment: If you are planning for extranet app then why sqlLite??

Comment: my project doesn't based extranet.I need to specify onyl mail server attriubutes.My app doesn't include client-server type.there is no http request.

Comment: I am not going to design such as 'Outlook'. I design only small app for have an account and login  for employee succesfully. I am not interested in after this. My boss said that exactly.

Comment: So, SharedPreferences is best for session management.